# Is it possible to specify ember component attributes as required similar to react propTypes?

Tags: ember.js

Is there any way to specify an attribute as required in ember >=1.13 so that if it is not passed in, it will provide a helpful and clear message?

I would guess, once `ember-validations` is finally updated, that would cover it. I was just wondering if there was something I may have missed.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, you could make use the new component hook `didReceiveAttrs` in your component to check for specific attributes yourself and throw a `console.warn` if you wanted.

Docs on the new component hooks in 1.13: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_component-lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late but there is now [ember-prop-types](https://github.com/ciena-blueplanet/ember-prop-types) which has an API almost identical to that of React.

Below is an example of consumption:

```
import Ember from 'ember'
import PropTypeMixin, {PropTypes} from 'ember-prop-types'

export default Ember.Component.extend(PropTypeMixin, {
  propTypes: {
    foo: PropTypes.string,
    bar: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    baz: PropTypes.oneOf([
      PropTypes.bool,
      PropTypes.string
    ])
  },

  getDefaultProps () {
    return {
      foo: 'This is going to be highly profitable'
    }
  }
})
```

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of the project.*

Comment: so proptypes are basically meant just for type checking?  what are the major use cases where we might want to use them ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Ember.assert](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_assert) as a default value for your property, that way if it isn't set you will get an error message.

```
Import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed, assert } = Ember;

myProperty: computed(function() { 
  return assert('My property cannot be empty');
})
```

Comment: Thats the route i'm taking at the moment. Working on a mixin that allows you to specify a `attrTypes` object ala https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Comment: @mattmcmanus what exactly is the problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: I have a component that I reuse a lot that has 4 different actions that bubble up the to routes (saveRecord, rollbackRecord, etc). I've had some bugs that I've missed where I didn't hand it an action. I've used react a lot in the past and really liked the propType definitions and the easy reminder that you missed something.

Comment: Can you add the component code to the question? The action part.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kilter mentioned above, the `Ember.assert` approach is the best way to go.

Here is a small example that, though not as declarative as React propTypes, works just as well.

```
didReceiveAttrs() {
  this._super(...arguments);

  assert('You must pass a model into the submit-button component', this.get('model'));
},
```